# JsonConvert.NumberFormat (Newtonsoft.Json 6.0 to 10.0)

Tags: c#, json

I was using JsonConvert.NumberFormat = "#.#"; with Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.Updating to 10.0 NumberFormat property is gone. Cannot find and easy fix. Anyone with similar issue?

Comment: The first place to start would be with the [release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases).

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't there. However, on JsonSerializerSettings I can set Culture's numberFormat. Problem solved.